# Append to text input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to append this to text input not to Paragraph tag `p` I try but I cant get it

my append codes

```
$(req.responseText).find('GetRecipeDetailResponse').each(function(){//Get the servings/yield
    var yield = $(this).find('Yield').text();
    $('#Yield').append('<p><h6>Servings: ' + yield + " servings"+ '</h6></p>')
    $('#Yield').fieldcontain('refresh')
});
```

Html Code:

```
  <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="Yield"><!--Yield-->

  </div>
```

Comment: Please explain *not to p.. Ill try*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use a valid selector, `$(this).find('Yield')` should probably be `$(this).find('#Yield')`, if you want it on an input (not sure i understand your question, but I think this is what you want):

```
$('#Yield').append('<p><h6>Servings: <input type="text" value="' + yield + '"> servings'+ '</h6></p>')
```

Comment: <input type="text" value="' + yield + '"> is an input box.  its default is whatever is in #Yield, but you can change the input.  Do you want to change the div with the id Yield?

Comment: actually that was I expecting but when I run my apps. it cannot change the input..

Answer (score 0):

Try this Examble

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("ol").append("<li>Appended item</li>");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<ol>
<li>List item 1</li>
<li>List item 2</li>
<li>List item 3</li>
</ol>

<button id="btn1">Append text</button>
<button id="btn2">Append list item</button>

</body>
</html>
```